# Add border(*) for rectangular matrix of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add * as borders for rectangular matrix of characters. For example,

```
["abc", "ded"]
```

should return

```
["*****","*abc*","*ded*","*****"]
```

What I did was I create a new matrix with 2 more rows and columns than the original one, and I filled it with *. So the problem is when I am replacing the * inside with original letters, I have an error of out of index. I couldn't quite figure out why?

```
def addBorder(picture):
  m=len(picture) #number of rows
  n=len(picture[0]) #num of columns
  newpic=[['*'*(n+2)]for y in range(m+2)] 
  for x in range(1,m+1):
    for y in range(1,n+1):
     newpic[x][y]=picture[x-1][y-1]
  return newpic
```

Comment: are you trying to mutate `str` inside of `newpic`?

Comment: what should happen in case of `picture` with non-equivalent-by-size `str`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you can not "edit" single characters inside them bey indexing into them - thats what you are trying in your `for x ..:  for y: ...` loop.

To keep most of your code, you can change it to:

```
def addBorder(picture):
  m=len(picture) #number of rows
  n=len(picture[0]) #num of columns
  newpic=[['*'*(n+2)]for y in range(m+2)] 

  for idx,text in enumerate(picture): # get text and index here
     newpic[idx+1] = '*' + text+ '*'  # change text in +1 row in target list
  return newpic 

print(addBorder( ["abc", "ded"]))
```

Output:

```
[['*****'], '*abc*', '*ded*', ['*****']]
```

Changing more code:

```
def addBorder(picture):
    # slightly more compley length computation, will work for ragged text as well
    maxL = max(len(x) for x in picture) 
    patt = "*{:<"+str(maxL)+"}*"   # left justified by maxL , see link below
    rv = []
    rv.append('*'*(maxL+2))    # top border

    for t in picture:
        rv.append(patt.format(t)) # text + adornment

    rv.append('*'*(maxL+2))    # bottom border

    return rv

print(addBorder( ["abc", "defgh","i"]))
```

Output:

```
['*******', 
 '*abc  *', 
 '*defgh*', 
 '*i    *', 
 '*******']
```

Link:  [string format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

---

<strike>Your out of index error message is somewhat misleading - you are inside the bounds of your lists, but you are trying to manipulate the string - I would have thought a `'str' object does not support item assignment` would be more appropriate here...</strike>

Edit: see [Azats answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51759697/7505395) for why your error occurs - I left text in so his post does not loose its reference.

[image: debugging your code]

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to

1. Create filled with * `newpic`.
2. Modify `newpic[1:-1]` and replace * (excluding borders) with `picture` elements contents.

This approach has a problem with `str` objects immutability, but even if they were mutable this seems to be inefficient to create **...** string and then mutate them character-by-character.

About your error: it isn't misleading as stated by @PatrickArtner, it originates from a typo (I guess), because you are creating `list`s of `list` of `str`:

```
>>> m = 3
>>> n = 4
>>> [['*'*(n+2)]for y in range(m+2)]
[['******'], ['******'], ['******'], ['******'], ['******']]
```

so when `y` equals to `1` you are getting this error (because each of `newpic` sublists has single `str` element inside of them).

Instead of trying to modify `list` of `str` we can create `list` and append `str` to it like

```
def addBorder(picture,
              border_size=1):
    max_substring_length = max(map(len, picture))
    # top border
    result = ['*' * (max_substring_length + border_size * 2)]
    for substring in picture:
        diff = max_substring_length - len(substring)
        additional_length, extra = divmod(diff, 2)
        # handling non-equivalent case
        prepend = '*' * (border_size + additional_length + extra)
        append = '*' * (border_size + additional_length)
        result.append(prepend + substring + append)
    # bottom border
    result.append('*' * (max_substring_length + border_size * 2))
    return result
```

## Test

```
for string in addBorder(["abc", "ded"]):
    print(string)
```

gives us

```
*****
*abc*
*ded*
*****
```

non-equivalent by size case

```
for string in addBorder(["abc", "deed"]):
    print(string)
```

gives us

```
******
**abc*
*deed*
******
```

Comment: Good catch - I oversaw the `[[""],]` - I edited mybotch but left it in so yours does keep its "referecing" point into mine.

Answer (score 1):

In C++

```
  std::vector<std::string> addBorder(std::vector<std::string> picture) 
  {
  for(auto &p: picture)
     p = "*"+p+"*";
  picture.insert(picture.begin(), string(picture[0].size(),'*'));
  picture.insert(picture.end(), string(picture[0].size(),'*'));
  return picture;
  }
```